# Worksheet Change event issue (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I have set up a worksheet_change vba code to track any changes in Sheet1, column(F). The idea is any new value entered, anywhere on Col(F), the value entered will be transferred to a log in Admin sheet Col(S).

My code:

```
Dim cell As String
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.range("F:F")) Is Nothing Then
cell = Target.address
Dim LR As Long
LR = Sheets("Admin").Cells(Rows.count, "S").End(xlUp).row
With Worksheets("Admin")
    For i = 7 To LR
    If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 19).Value) Then
        .range(i, 19).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").range(cell)
    Else
    GoTo nextitr
    End If

nextitr:
    Next i
End With
End If
End Sub
```

I have done some research and I did try to envelope my code with:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
'code'
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

But that does not work either.

I am quite unsure where I am going wrong. Perhaps my logic is not working in this instance? Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simpler way to do this. No need to loop, check if a cell is empty, or store `Target.Address`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In Target
        If Not Intersect(rng, Me.Range("F:F")) Is Nothing Then
            Sheets("Admin").Cells(Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = rng.Value
        End If
    Next rng
End Sub
```